# Parsing fails with big JSON objects (rtweet)

Tags: r, json, rtweet

I'm trying to parse big JSON files with the function `parse_stream()` function from rwteet library. It fails with long JSON objects.

This JSON objects tends to generate an error when they have considerable size (200MB-1GB). My stream function looks like this.

```
    stream_tweets(
        "#google,#apple",
        timeout = 60*60*6, #six hours
        file_name = json_filename,
        dir= "./raw_tweets/"
      )

    djt <- parse_stream(json_filename)
```

I didn't enable the `parse = TRUE` parameter because in [documentation](https://rtweet.info/reference/stream_tweets.html) it says that is not recommended at big JSON objects. Anyway I also tried to stream with `parse = TRUE` and also fails at `parse_stream()`. The error that I'm getting is the folowing one:

```
Error: parse error: unallowed token at this point in JSON text
      ELDkx4-i7ysCAR_.mp4?tag=10"},,{"bitrate":2176000,"content_ty
                 (right here) ------^
```

I thought it was the double comma between the two curl braces. I searched at Atom using *ctrl+f* the string `ELDkx4-i7ysCAR_.mp4?tag=10"}` and in the only result there was not `,,`.

Why I'm getting this parse error, has someone had the samme issue and fix it somehow?

Answer (score 0):

I think that this happens when it has connection errors during the stream. I think that when it connect again the json